# unity 2d fixed button / HUD on camera move

Tags: unity-game-engine

i want to have 2 fixed buttons on the top of my scene while the main camera is moving up (back, restart, ...) - 2D

```
menu button sprite = layer "menu"
main camera = culling mask all except layer "menu", depth -1
2nd camer = culling mask only layer "menu", depth 0
```

all is working fine but i just want to know if this is the correct way showing buttons HUDs on a fixed position

thanks

Comment: why don't you use [Unity UI](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html)?

Comment: never used UI / Canvas elements...

Comment: It doesn't mean that you **will** never use it :)

Comment: Agreed. Use Canvas. it's simple to learn and the Unity documentation is good. It is definitely the best fit for what you want to achieve here.